# What is the literal meaning of Valparaíso?

Tags: traducción, pronunciación

I've heard people pronounce the Chilean city "Val puh RI zo", but now that I'm learning Spanish I realize that can't be right; it must be something like: "bval par uh EE so" no?

The "paraiso" means paradise, but what is the "val" part? Does Valparaiso mean "paradise valley" or "paradisaic valley" or...???

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, the correct pronunciation would be
`Bal - pa - ra - EE - so`

> Al fracasar en su misión de encontrar metales preciosos en la Terra
>   Australis, Almagro volvió a Cuzco donde comenzó una lucha fratricida
>   con Pizarro. En este conflicto, se destacó en el bando de Pizarro el
>   capitán **Pedro de Valdivia**, cuya presencia ayudó a la posterior
>   victoria sobre Almagro.
>
> A petición propia, **Pizarro le otorgó a Valdivia permiso para
>   "conquistar" Chile.** **Su primer acto oficial fue la fundación de** la
>   ciudad de **Santiago de la Nueva Extremadura** en 1541, **siendo designado
>   Valparaíso** como su puerto natural el 3 de septiembre de 1544.

http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valpara%C3%ADso

The `Val` in `Valparaíso` refers to the founder, and captain, Pedro de Valdivia.

More information, in English
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valdivia#Independence_and_growth_.281811.E2.80.931959.29

So, literally, it would mean Val's Paradise. or Valdivia's Paradise.

Comment: That might be inaccurate, as Valparaíso was never officially founded (see "Fundación" in http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valpara%C3%ADso)

Comment: @dockeryz This is plain inaccurate. There is no mention on the links that "Val" refers to Pedro de Valdivia. Check the answer from Jose Maria. Also check your own link http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valpara%C3%ADso#Toponimia . This is simply -1.

Comment: @Envite, I wasn't the one who added the green check mark either.

Comment: @dockeryz A green mark does not mean that your answer is right; just that the person who wrote the question thinks so. Envite and anyone else are very right on commenting or downvoting your answer if they think it is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

how say ailnlv, Valparaíso was never officially founded. indigenous of the area was called "Aliamapu" that means scorched earth. But nobody knows the real origin of the word valparaiso

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valpara%C3%ADso

please, visit this city, it's very very beautiful

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P4pBnyYaCoc